# Check network speed

Tags: networking, router

Is there a way to check that my network is alternating between the routers to the Internet?

I wasn't the one that set up our network. Physically I can see that we have one phone line into the our server room which is then connected to two routers and then into the firewall (pfSense). From what I have learned from the other people here is that it should work like this: If one router is down the server automatically should change and use the other router. But from what I see as the behavior of the network it is that if one router goes down, the network almost goes to a halt. Not slows down in speed as I expect. Is there a way to check if the network is doing as it should? Because it could also just be that I'm inexperienced and have lack of knowledge about how network works.

Thank you,
Nitman

Comment: Yes. Pull the network connection on your main router and see if the failover happens correctly.

Comment: Down and reduced performance are different things. If the network is only at a snail's pace it is still UP.

Comment: Yes, it is at a snail's pace so maybe it is as expected then. But the understanding I have is that since it is only one line/cable in it should have the same speed whether one or two routers are connected. Or does the router work as a bottleneck if only one router is working? Can I improve speed more if I use a third router?

Comment: Depending on configuration a snails pace probably means the router is still up and thus has no reason to fail over. A third router will not help. Also curious how it fails over? A list of preferred WAPs and the clients actually handle the failover?